# How to handle a large datalogger csv file / playback in java

Tags: java, performance, csv

I have a datalogger that produces a CSV file containing UTC time and 4 parameters.  The UTC time is logged ABOUT every 30ms followed by the 4 parameters.  The problem I have is 2 fold:

1) The CSV file is potentially huge if I run the datalogger for even an hour.
2) The UTC time is not exactly every 30ms.

In my simple design for a replay of the data I had planned to load the file, split each entry at character "'" then assign the values in a loop though the UTC time value and then load the 4 parameters, but with the file so large I am concerned it wont work or will be very slow.  I am new to java and am not sure if the there is a better way to handle so much data (I suspect there is!).

My plan to loop through and repeat he filling of 4 variables for the parameters wont work as the UTC entries are not exact.  I had planned to take a decimal place off the data, but that clearly looses me fidelity in the replay of my data.  I want to be able to construct a "timeline" in my application to allow play pause stop style functionality hence my problem handling the UTC time.

Here is a sample of some of the data when the time is pretty tight, this isnt always the case:

```
,13:35:38.772,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:38.792,0,0,-0.0439453125,0.3515625
,13:35:38.822,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:38.842,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:38.872,0,0,0.0439453125,0.3515625
,13:35:38.892,0,0,0,0.3076171875
,13:35:38.922,0,0,0,0.3076171875
,13:35:38.942,0,0,0,0.3076171875
,13:35:38.962,0,0,0.0439453125,0.3515625
,13:35:38.992,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:39.012,0,0,0,0.3076171875
,13:35:39.042,0,0,-0.0439453125,0.3076171875
,13:35:39.072,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:39.092,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:39.112,0,0,0.0439453125,0.3076171875
,13:35:39.142,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:39.162,0,0,0,0.3076171875
,13:35:39.192,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:39.212,0,0,0,0.3076171875
,13:35:39.242,0,0,0,0.3515625
,13:35:39.262,0,0,0,0.3076171875
```

I realise this is a broad question, but I am looking for a general steer in how to tackle the problem.  Code is welcome, but I am expecting to have to ask more questions as time goes on.

Thanks for the help;

Andy

Comment: If speed is a big factor, this set of performance metrics for string splitting might interest you: http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance/

Comment: Why do you need it to be fast and how fast? You have some 40 chars per line, 3600/0.030 = 120000 lines per hour, this is half a megabyte. This may take a second or about.

Comment: Interesting that your maths came out at about a second or so.  I imported the file into libreoffice and it took around 15mins on my Core I7 with 16gb of ram!  That speed scared me off my planned implementation.

Comment: Actually it is 5 meg for a 1 hour file. Try a specialist CSV editor; they should load the file a lot faster 15 mins

Comment: Can you recommend a good CSV editor for a guy learning java?